Why is my code failing trying to post a tweet with an image using twitter-api-v2 library in Node.js?
Here is the code in Node.js:
Also, for some reason, then-catch doesn't catch the error.
import { TwitterApi } from 'twitter-api-v2';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXX';
const CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXX';
const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'XXX';
const ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'XXX';
const BEARER_TOKEN = 'XXX';

// Replace with your API keys and tokens
const client = new TwitterApi({
  appKey: CONSUMER_KEY,
  appSecret: CONSUMER_SECRET,
  accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN,
  accessSecret: ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
});

const tweets = [];

function postTweets(folderPath) {
  fs.readdir(folderPath, (error, files) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.error('Unable to scan directory: ' + error);
    }
    files.forEach(file => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
      console.log(`Trying to post next tweet: ${path.basename(filePath)}`);
      const text = 'Some text';
      // Upload the image to Twitter
      client.v1.uploadMedia(filePath)
        .then(mediaId => {
          console.log('Media successfully uploaded');
          // Post the tweet with the text and the uploaded image
          client.v1.tweet(text, { media_ids: mediaId })
            .then(tweet => {
              console.log('Tweet successfully posted:', tweet.id);
              tweets.push(tweet.data.id);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log('Tweet post failed', error);
            })
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log('Media upload failed', error);
        })

    });
  })
}

postTweets('d:/Pictures/Twitter/Images');

Why am I getting these non-descriptive error messages?
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\twitter.js
Trying to post next tweet: 001.png
Trying to post next tweet: 002.png
Trying to post next tweet: 003.png
Media upload failed Error: Request failed with code 403
    at RequestHandlerHelper.createResponseError (d:\Projects\NodeApps\node_modules\twitter-api-v2\dist\cjs\client-mixins\request-handler.helper.js:104:16)
    at RequestHandlerHelper.onResponseEndHandler (d:\Projects\NodeApps\node_modules\twitter-api-v2\dist\cjs\client-mixins\request-handler.helper.js:262:25)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (d:\Projects\NodeApps\lib\events.js:531:35)
    at endReadableNT (d:\Projects\NodeApps\lib\internal\streams\readable.js:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {error: true, type: 'response', code: 403, headers: {…}, rateLimit: undefined, …}
Media upload failed Error: Request failed with code 403
    at RequestHandlerHelper.createResponseError (d:\Projects\NodeApps\node_modules\twitter-api-v2\dist\cjs\client-mixins\request-handler.helper.js:104:16)
    at RequestHandlerHelper.onResponseEndHandler (d:\Projects\NodeApps\node_modules\twitter-api-v2\dist\cjs\client-mixins\request-handler.helper.js:262:25)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (d:\Projects\NodeApps\lib\events.js:531:35)
    at endReadableNT (d:\Projects\NodeApps\lib\internal\streams\readable.js:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {error: true, type: 'response', code: 403, headers: {…}, rateLimit: undefined, …}
Media upload failed Error: Request failed with code 403
    at RequestHandlerHelper.createResponseError (d:\Projects\NodeApps\node_modules\twitter-api-v2\dist\cjs\client-mixins\request-handler.helper.js:104:16)
    at RequestHandlerHelper.onResponseEndHandler (d:\Projects\NodeApps\node_modules\twitter-api-v2\dist\cjs\client-mixins\request-handler.helper.js:262:25)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (d:\Projects\NodeApps\lib\events.js:531:35)
    at endReadableNT (d:\Projects\NodeApps\lib\internal\streams\readable.js:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {error: true, type: 'response', code: 403, headers: {…}, rateLimit: undefined, …}

